# build latest Gnome from source Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, source

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 with gnome 3.20.4

I wanted to know if it possible to build the latest gnome from source on my Ubuntu, from git using the [guide](https://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/source/)